# Correct approach for performing retrospective A/B testing on existing data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ab-test

I have large amounts of data about events and historical behavior (clicks, purchases etc) of users on a site. I would like to be able to correlate the inputs (like clicks, purchases, other events) with the outputs of interest (lifetime order value of customer etc).

Can I use the exact same math and process that I would use for a typical A/B test, where I don't have the data ahead of time? Or, is there a different approach that should be taken in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it is a hypothesis testing problem. What you describe is a classification or regression problem, depending of the type of the output variable (categorial or real). This is the field of Machine Learning: you feed learning algorithm with historical data and you create a model. That model is used to make predictions on unseen data.